# Equivalent to Powershell in batch

Tags: json, powershell, batch-file

Did exist an equivalent to this command in batch :

```
Powershell -nop  -c "(cat test.json | ConvertFrom-Json).nodes | where {$_.id -eq item1'} | foreach {$_.apps.id} | tee output.txt"
```

With using "for" command :

```
for /f "tokens=1,2" %%i in (test.json) do....
```

My company disabled powershell so I can't use Powershell command...

JSON file :

```
"nodes": [
    {
    "id": "item1",
    "apps": [
    {
      "id": "value1",             
    },
    {
      "id": "value2",     
    },

    {
      "id": "value2",     
    },

    "id": "item2",
  "apps": [
    {
      "id": "value1",

    },
    {
      "id": "value2",  
    },

    {
      "id": "value2",  
    },
```

UPDATE :

I tried to use a function of my .ps1 file but it doesn't work. It is probably because my command is wrong. How can I implement that well ?

Convert-Json.ps1 :

```
function ConvertTo-Json20([object] $item){
    add-type -assembly system.web.extensions
    $ps_js=new-object system.web.script.serialization.javascriptSerializer
    return $ps_js.Serialize($item)
}

function ConvertFrom-Json20([object] $item){ 
    add-type -assembly system.web.extensions
    $ps_js=new-object system.web.script.serialization.javascriptSerializer

    #The comma operator is the array construction operator in PowerShell
    return ,$ps_js.DeserializeObject($item)
}
```

batch file :

```
Powershell -nop  -c "(cat ". .\Convert-Json.ps1; ConvertFrom-Json20 -item "myfile.json").nodes | where {$_.id -eq '%%i'} | foreach {$_.apps.id} | tee %mode%\%%i\services_%%i.txt"
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Your JSON file is invalid..

Comment: you can take a look at [jsonextractor.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/jsonextractor.bat) and use it like  `call jsonextractor.bat json.file "nodes[1].id"` and see if it will be useful for you. But it is not so powerful as the powershell cmdlets.

Comment: In such a case, you really need to talk with your boss instead of trying to find a work-around. Explain that you use Powershell for JSON parsing and now you cannot do a part of your work as Powershell is disabled.

Comment: I guess it will be too complicated in batch. You may try do it with python, or other programming language. Even if you can't install software, just copy paste python.exe (or other) to your working directory

Comment: @npocmaka Thanks you ! Now if i want to have this "where {$_.id -eq '!%machine_%%i!'} | foreach {$_.apps.id}" what I need to add with this instruction call jsonextractor.bat json.file "nodes[1].id" ?

Comment: What scripting language ARE available to you? VBScript?  Perl?  Parsing json is going to be difficult (impossible? a nightmare?) with just the basic cmd choices.

Comment: Of course... if I had choice I would go to python... but I have no choice... that's why I post this question for know if it possible to do it... Powershell is disable and I can't download every IDE or use any other language...

Comment: What does "my company disabled PowerShell" mean, specifically? PowerShell is a built-in part of the Windows OS starting in Windows 7.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart OP is possibly referring to [execution policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies?view=powershell-6). It is possible to stop scripts from running, which fits OP's description of unable to use a ps1 script.

Comment: You're mistaken there. [Execution policy is an administrator safety feature, not a security feature.](https://westmesatech.com/?p=33)